# Powershell (Version 2.0) remote execution of services with credentials

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, powershell-2.0

I want to start/stop apache and mysql services on remote machine by using powershell version 2.0 (Windows Server 2008). I found syntax for remote execution as follow:

```
(Get-WmiObject -Computer myCompName Win32_Service -Filter "Name='myServiceName'").InvokeMethod("Stop-Service",$null)
```

But I have to provide credentials (DOMAIN_NAME\USERNANE and PASSWORD) also for this exceution. I am new to powershell and need help for correct syntax (example will be easy to understand and implement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Get-WMIObject` accepts the `-Credential` parameter. You shouldn't be keeping your credentials in plain text in your script, so you'll want to prompt for them.

```
$creds = get-credential;
(Get-WmiObject -Computer myCompName Win32_Service -Filter "Name='myServiceName'" -credential $creds).InvokeMethod("Stop-Service",$null)
```

If you have PSRemoting enabled on the remote system, you can do this without WMI.

```
$creds = get-credential;
Invoke-Command -computername myCompName -credential $creds -scriptblock {(get-service -name myServiceName).Stop()};
```

---

Update based on comments

Since you're running this as a scheduled job, you should not be storing or prompting for credentials at all. Configured the scheduled job itself (via Scheduled Tasks) to run under the required user account, then either of the following should work:

```
# Your original code
(Get-WmiObject -Computer myCompName Win32_Service -Filter "Name='myServiceName'").InvokeMethod("Stop-Service",$null)
# If you have remoting enabled
Invoke-Command -computername myCompName -scriptblock {(get-service -name myServiceName).Stop()};
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply. I want to know how I can pass DOMAIN_NAME\USERNANE and PASSWORD. As I need to create shedule task so it should not prompt for credentials. May be storing details in a .txt file will work. I am not powershell programer so let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: The fact that you're doing it as a scheduled task should have been in your original post. You shouldn't be storing the credentials in plain-text *anywhere*. Configure the scheduled task to execute *as that user*. Then skip everything around credentials in my post.

Comment: I missed the option run as a particular user will help me without storing password. As administartor I am able to start/stop service by (get-service -ComputerName myCompName -Name myServiceName).Stop() . I will implement my requirement as per your suggestion. Thanks a lot.